# Azure DML Data slices?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have 40 mil blobs of 10 TB in blob storage. I am using [DML](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) `CopyDirectory` to copy these into another storage account for backup purpose. It took nearly 2 weeks to complete. Now i am worried that until which date the blobs are copied to target directory. Is it the date when the job started or the date job finished ?

Does DML uses anything like data slices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now i am worried that until which date the blobs are copied to target directory. Is it the date when the job started or the date job finished ?

As far as I know, when you start the CopyDirectory method, it will just send the request to tell the azure storage account to copy files from another storage account. All the copy operation is azure storage.

If we run the method to start copy the directory, the azure storage will firstly create the file with 0 size as below:

[image]

After the job finished, you will find it has change the size as below:

[image]

So the result is if the job started it will create the file in the target directory, but the file size is 0. You could see image1's file last modify time.

The azure storage will continue copy the file content to the target directory.

If the job finished, it will change the file last modify time.

So the DML SDK just tell the storage to copy files, then it will continue send the request to the azure storage to check each file's copy status.

Like below:

[image]

> Thanks. But what happens if the files added to the source directory during this copy operation ? Does the new files as well get copied to the target directory ?

In short answer Yes.

The DML won't get the whole blob list and send request to copy all the file at one time.

It will firstly get a part of your file name list and send request to tell the storage copy file.

The list is sort by the file name.

For example.

If the DML have already copied the file name like 0 file as below.

This target blob folder

[image]

If you add the 0 start file to your folder,it will not copy.

This is copy from blob folder.

[image]

Copy completely blob folder:

[image]

If you add the file at the end of your blob folder and the DML doesn't scan it, it will be copied to the new folder.

---

> so during that 2 weeks at least a million blobs must have been added to the container with very random names. So i think DML doesn't work in the case of large containers ?

As far as I know, the DML is designed for high-performance uploading, downloading and copying Azure Storage Blob and File.

When you using the DML CopyDirectoryAsync to copy the blob file.It will firstly send a request to list the folder's current file, then it will send the request to copy the file.

The default of the operation sending a request to list the folder's current file number is 250.

After get list it will generate a marker which is the next blob search file names. It will start to list the next file name in the folder and start copy again.

And by default, the .Net HTTP connection limit is 2. This implies that only two concurrent connections can be maintained.

It means if you don't set the .Net HTTP connection limit, the CopyDirectoryAsync will just get 500 record and start copy.

After copy completely, the operation will start to copy next files.

You could see this images:

[image]

The marker:

[image]

I suggest you could firstly set the max http connections to detect more blob files.

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = Environment.ProcessorCount * 8;
```

Besides, I suggest you could create multiple folder to store the files.

For example, you could create a folder which stores one week files.

Next week, you could start a new folder.

Then you could backup the old folder's file without new files store into that folder.

Finally, you could also write your own code to achieve your requirement, you need firstly get the list of the folder's files.

The max result of one request to get the list is 5000.

Then you could send the request to tell the storage copy each files.

If the file upload to the folder after you get the list, it will not copy to the new folder.

Comment: Thanks. But what happens if the files added to the source directory during this copy operation ? Does the new files as well get copied to the target directory ?

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. But, As i said ,i have more than 40 mil blobs in one container. So it's impossible to know where the new file has been added. As i also said, the full backup of container is taking 2 weeks. so during that 2 weeks at least a million blobs must have been added to the container with very random names.  So i think DML doesn't work in the case of large containers ?